# Safari clipboard permissions checking

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, clipboard

I have the following code that works in Chrome:

```
navigator.permissions
    .query({ name: "clipboard-write" })
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.state === "granted" || result.state === "prompt") {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(data.payload).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ToSystemClipboard", err);
    });
```

But in Safari it hits the catch with `TypeError: Type error`.

In Webstorm I get an underlining of `{ name: "clipboard-write" }` to the effect that `clipboard-write` is not a recognised keyword. And yet on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read `clipboard-read` is used in an example - I can't recall where I found `clipboard-write`.

If I remove the permissions test, my code -  `navigator.clipboard.writeText` - works in Safari anyway, but that doesn't feel like the safest code to write for production. Am I missing something?

I have since found that "[[t]he clipboard-write permission is granted automatically to pages when they are the active tab](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/)". This explains why my code works without the permissions check, but does not answer my question about syntax to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clipboard-read` and `clipboard-write` are [unavailable to Firefox or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API#browser_compatibility) via the `navigator.permissions.query` function.

However you can access Safari's clipboard via [`navigator.clipboard` instead](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/).

You'll find that only the more recent versions of Safari supports `query` so make sure you check for availability: `navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({ ...`